# Accessing a usb device through wireless connection

Tags: android, usb, wireless

What I want to achieve, is to make a usb device accessible remotely. Next the device will be connected to an android phone which will contact the server through wireless. I would like to avoid writing a complete handler for the transactions. My approach would like to be a bit abstract and as simple as possible I want the usb  to be mapped on the network interface, in a way like the phone will actually work as a proxy for the availability of the usb.

Answer (score 0):

And what is your question exactly ? 
What kind of devices do you want to connect ?
Ive heart that only android 3.0 can act as usb host ( not sure on this one) 
If you can use a industrial device they os supports it http://www.ozdroid.com/#!PRODUCTS

May be some mods can also act as usb hosts

is this the architecture you are trying to achieve ?

[COMPUTER]->(internet/wlan)->[Android]->[USB Keyboard]

There is no abstract/easy way to do this as far as I know the android api does not support anything like that.

May be there are some solutions for this using linux take a look on the android/debian installer   ( needs root)

Something like that will probably need at least some native code if not directly a kernel module ...

IF you crate a proxy for a concrete device (for example a keyboard) you could send the keyboard events to a java ( or other) application on the computer but you need  usb host support on the device.

Comment: The usb device is a programmable controller for a flying object. I can pass instructions to the controller for the flying behavior of it, if its connected with usb on my computer. What I would like to do is keep passing instructions to it. The architecture is exactly that with the keyboard part replaced with the controller!

Comment: the industry device I mentioned has also a uart port may be you could use it ( for example if the controller uses a ftdi chip http://www.ftdichip.com/)  you also could control the plane directly with the phone

Comment: If you want to do it using this architecture the android device has to understand the connected device eq you will need a driver than you can program a native library which  passes the data to a java program or directly to the PC  There is a linux driver for the ftdi chip